# BASH SHELL IF ELSE run command in background

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, if-statement

I have used the `&` command before to make a script run another script in the background like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"    
script1.sh &
script2.sh &
echo "Please wait..."
```

But lets say I have another script with an IF ELSE statment and I would like to set an ELIF statement mid flow as a background task with the `&` and then carry on with processing the rest of my script knowing that while rest of the ELIF will carry running in the back ground:

```
#!/bin/bash
if cond1; then
   stuff
   sleep 10 &
   stuff
   stuff
elif cond2; then
   something else
else 
   echo "foo"
fi
stuff
echo "Hello World"
```

I really hope this makes sense any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run your commands in a [**subshell**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html). A subshell will execute in a separate (child) process. You can define which commands are ran in a subshell by surrounding them with parentheses.

And, as you know, to run a process in the background just append an `&`.

---

Here is what your `if` statement would look like if you were to execute it in a separate, background, process:

```
#!/bin/bash
( if cond1; then
    stuff
    sleep 10 &
    stuff
    stuff
 elif cond2; then
    something else
 else 
    echo "foo"
 fi
 stuff
 echo "Hello World" ) &
```

Comment: Basic summary: wrap the body you wish to execute in `(` and `) &`.

Comment: Using '{ list; }&' will also work to group the commands.  The list will be run in a subshell as a result of the '&'.